# Delete entire DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

Is there a method to remove/delete the entire Data table in C# once I am finished with? I only see methods to remove the values in the rows/columns but not the actual table itself.

Comment: A DataTable is an object in memory; there is nothing to delete.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The garbage collector should dispose of it at the end of the scope. Otherwise, you can just set the entire table to `null`: `DataTable yourTable = null;`

Comment: Seeing your code may help us answer you fully. The best way to "remove/delete" it could depend on how was the DataTable created - for example, did you create a new instance of DataTable and is it part of a DataSet.

Comment: @Symon: kinda-sorta.  The `yourTable` in the code you show is a variable of type `DataTable` (which is a class/reference-type).  So, the variable holds a reference to the DataTable object of interest.  By setting `yourTable` to null, that object is no longer referenced by that variable.  If there are no other references to that object, it will be eligible for garbage collection.  But, it doesn't _"set the entire table to `null`"_

Comment: Maybe elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: This may also be what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.reset?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Reset